# GATE ANNIE Gazetteer lookup word containing colon

Tags: gate

I want to add a new lookup list to the ANNIE Gazetteer. Some of the words which shall be found contain colons; and a feature in the annotations (which are defined in the new mylookup.list) contain also colons, for example:

```
mylookup.lst:
Star Wars:Episode I:url=http://example.com
```

So it shall find the String `Star Wars:Episode I` and annotate it with `url`=`http://example.com`

I already tried to "escape" the colons in my mylookup.lst with `\`, but it didn't work. Because I also want to use the other default lookup lists (which are all colon-separated) I can't just define an other separator.
So how can I tell the gazetteer to lookup and annotate words that contain colons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no support for escaping separator characters in `.lst` files. You have to choose other separator character. I recommend the tab character: `\t`

In that case you cannot use the default (colon-separated) lookup lists in the same gazetteer PR. But you can use two separate gazetteer PRs in your pipeline. One for the default lookup lists and a second one for the new lists with the different separator.

Comment: OK, thank you for this information. So I have to do it this way =/